# Unity | Script to create a new Tag

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, dynamic

I have a code which reads multiple string-arrays out of a **dynamical** dll. I'm creating GameObjects out of each string inside that array and i want to group each array of strings as unique groups.
So far, I've managed to give theese GameObject specific tags to group them, but theese tags were pre-created in the Unity Editor. This works so far, but in case the dynamic class provides more arrays than tags i have created previously, it won't be able to group the additional arrays.

My question: is there any way to create new tags via script while the game is running? With theese i could just simply add them to the new GameObjects.

In case that this shouldn't be possible, does someone have an idea of a different way to sort theese groups?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO, you'll be better off creating your own ```DynamicTag``` system as, afaik, the Unity tag system is pretty simple and mostly pre-compiled.  I'll try to code something for you tomorrow, but basically, have a MonoBehaviour that 'tags' the object and can register itself with its own static dictionary.

Comment: While waiting for immersive did you tried looking into [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/33597/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tag-programmatically.html?_ga=2.138157491.241387719.1604331271-1974647004.1590296638)

Comment: I wrote a really awesome "This is how you do custom tags in Unity" answer... which didn't actually address your specific situation.  I'll try again... =)

Comment: @Immersive thank you very much for going out of your way to create a little code for this usecase! i'll try it out later this day and see if this works for me.

Comment: @Ginxxx yeah I've already tried to look into it, but to me it seemed like that this isnt helping me out that much. To my understanding, this isn't working while the game is actually running and can only be executed while beeing in the editor.  I will look into it again, thanks!

Comment: This maybe help it some way that instead of giving new tags why not encapsulate them with an enum ?? Because it seems like you are giving yourself a hard time doing the tagging in game.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the tag system is just a Dictionary of Lists. The problem is that Unity's Dictionary us defined at compile-time.  The downside of rolling your own Tag system is you need some way to clear destroyed objects.

```
public class CustomTag : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>> Collection = new Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>>();

    public static void Register(string tag, GameObject item) {

        if (!Collection.ContainsKey(tag))
            Collection.Add(tag, new List<GameObject>());

        Collection[tag].Add(item);
    }

    public static void Deregister(string tag, GameObject item) {

        if (!Collection.ContainsKey(tag))
            return; // No Such Tag

        // In case of multiple entries, remove all occurences of item
        // If you're sure you will only have one entry per item, you can just use 'Remove'
        Collection[tag].RemoveAll(m => m == item);

    }

    public static IEnumerable<GameObject> FindObjectsWithTag(string tag) {

        if (!Collection.ContainsKey(tag))
            return null;

        return Collection[tag].AsEnumerable();
    }

    public string Tag;

    private void Start() {
        Register(Tag, gameObject);
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        Deregister(Tag, gameObject);
    }
}
```

Add this component to each GameObject you create, and set the Tag.  It will take care of registering and deregistering.  You can access the list of objects per tag using `CustomTag.FindObjectsWithTag()`.  Note that with the current setup, objects won't register with the tag system until they Awake (which IIRC won't be until just before *next* update)